# Events on dynamically loaded form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a problem with loaded form. It doesn't trigger any events.
Here's the form:

```
<form id ="form1" method="post" action="newjsp.jsp">
<h2>Form1</h2>
<p>
<span style="margin-left: 4px">Number:</span>
<input type="hidden" name="form_number" value="1"/>
<input class="textBox" type="text" name="number" value=""/>
</p>
<p>
<input id="the_button" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Set"/>
</p>
</form>
```

I've tried basic examples with .on(), .live() and .delegate(), but none of those seems to work. I want to validate if number is 11 digits long. If not, stop submitting.
Here's jQuery:

```
$("#form1").submit(function e(){
if($(".textbox").length != 11)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#output").append("<p style='color:red;'>Please enter a valid number!</p>");
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation with `.on()` because the form is dynamically created. Also you have the `e` argument in the wrong place so your `preventDefault()` call would fail.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form1', function(e){
    if($(".textBox").val().length != 11)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#output").append("<p style='color:red;'>Please enter a valid number!</p>");
    }
});
```

Also you have a problem with your `textBox` class name, in the form you use `textBox` but in the Javascript you use `textbox`. Finally, use `$('.textBox').val().length` to get the length not `$('.textBox').length`. The latter will only give you the number of elements that were selected, not the number of characters in the input value.

Answer (score -1):

Move "e" inside the parenthesis and it works:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e){
if($(".textbox").length != 11)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#output").append("<p style='color:red;'>Please enter a valid number!</p>");
    }
});
```